# Error(Multiple Relations) While Coding SQL

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2010

I'm writing a sql query in Access 2010 and getting an error message saying that the field I am selecting is used in multiple relations so I need to select from just one table. I thought that I had the correct code for explicitly telling it which table to select from but I am still getting that error.

This is my code:

```
SELECT I.ingredientID, ingredientTypeCode, ingredientName, amount, unitCode
FROM Ingredient AS I
INNER JOIN BatchIngredient AS B ON I.ingredientID=B.ingredientID
ORDER BY ingredientID;
```

Shouldn't specifying I.ingredientID say that it will pull ingredientID from Ingredient and ignore BatchIngredient?

Comment: Are there more field names that occur in both tables?

Comment: Just ingredientID is contained in both tables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `ingredientID` is present in both tables, the db engine will find this ambiguous ...

```
ORDER BY ingredientID
```

I think you need ...

```
ORDER BY I.ingredientID
```

I would just go ahead and add the aliases in the `SELECT` clause, too.  Replace each `X` with the appropriate alias.

```
SELECT I.ingredientID, X.ingredientTypeCode, X.ingredientName, X.amount, X.unitCode
```

Comment: Great! By adding the "I." into the ORDER BY statement it worked. Thank you!